# CREATE USER and CREATE ROLE as PreparedStatement with ? placeholder

Tags: jdbc, parameters, prepared-statement

I am trying to issue a `CREATE USER` statement against a HSQLDB database from Java code in a way that allows the use of parameters.

However, the following line:

```
connection.prepareStatement("CREATE USER ? PASSWORD ?;");
```

throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ? in statement [CREATE USER ? PASSWORD ?;]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at (somewhere in my code)
```

The same happens for

```
connection.prepareStatement("CREATE ROLE ?;");
```

Of course, I could assemble my string without `?`, by pasting the values directly into the statement, though that would open up some potential for SQL injection.

So I am wondering why placeholders are not working. Are they supported in these statements at all? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, databases only allow parameters in DML, not in DDL. And in DML, it is only allowed for **values**. In the case of `CREATE USER` and `CREATE ROLE`, you aren't dealing with values but *identifiers* (at least not for the user or role name), so parameterization is not possible for those. This is similar to not allowing parameters for the table name or column name in a select statement.

In theory, something like the password in the `PASSWORD` clause is a value and could be parameterized, but in practice this isn't possible (at least, not that I'm aware of), as all DDL is handled as non-parameterizable.

As a minor form of protection against SQL injection, since JDBC 4.3 (introduced in Java 9), you can use [`Statement.enquoteIdentifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteIdentifier(java.lang.String,boolean)) to quote identifiers, and [`Statement.enquoteLiteral`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteLiteral(java.lang.String)) for literals like passwords. These methods have a default implementation, but if you're using a platform with non-standard identifier quotes (e.g. like MySQL), then you must make sure it is actually overridden (which isn't the case in current versions of MySQL Connector/J AFAIK).